# How to solve class cast exception when using a spinner with customized fonts as it items and setting the selected font to an edittext in android?

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, android-spinner, classcastexception

In my app I have an `EditText`, a `Button` and a `Spinner`. When the button is clicked it has to show the spinner. The `Spinner` shows various fonts and when a font is selected the font has to be applied to the text in the `EditText`. I have written the code but I am getting `NullPointerException` and I am not able to solve it.
Please help me asap.

Here is the Code:

```
public class FlipCardActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

ImageButton btn_from,btn_msg_tap,btn_font;
EditText edt_aroundMsg;
String edt_aroundMsgText = null;
Spinner spnr_font;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flip_card);
    edt_aroundMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_aroundMsg);        
    spnr_font = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_font);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(FlipCardActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.array.fonts);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnr_font.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnr_font.setOnItemSelectedListener(FlipCardActivity.this);
    addListenerOnButton();
    loadSavedPreferences();
}

private void addListenerOnButton() {
    btn_font = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_font);
    btn_font.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spnr_font.performClick();
        }
    }); 
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    spnr_font.setSelection(position);
    String str_font = (String) spnr_font.getSelectedItem();
    if ("Fondamento".equals(str_font)){
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Fondamento-        Regular.ttf");
        EditText edt_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_aroundMsg);
        edt_msg.setTypeface(tf);
    }


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

In my XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
tools:context=".FlipCardActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout_flip_card"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_aroundMsg"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_aroundRec"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/logo_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_rec"
        android:background="@drawable/border_message"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>

  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnr_font"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_hint"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat error file:

```
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.postcare2/com.sample.postcare2.FlipCardActivity}:    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to   android.widget.Spinner
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at com.sample.postcare2.FlipCardActivity.onCreate(FlipCardActivity.java:38)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
11-12 18:09:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(8367):     ... 11 more
```

11-12 18:10:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(8433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-12 18:10:08.086: E/AndroidRuntime(8433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.postcare2/com.sample.postcare2.FlipCardActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: This happens sometime. What i did was that i changed the id of the spinner and it worked

Comment: I tried cleaning the project and it didn't give me an exception. It depends on where I lay the spinner in the layout.

Comment: But I have got a new problem now I can see something like a spinner on the screen but no items in it. It just looks like a line with an arrow pointing downwards. I am not sure how I can attach an image here with the comment to make anyone understand better. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are viewing `activity_flip_card`? The crash indicates `spnr_font` is a TextView and not a Spinner. My guess is that `activity_flip_card` is not the right xml file

Answer (score 0):

make individual xml for the spinner item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_vehilcles_child_item_for_item_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Item Name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_50"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/smalldot"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:textSize="23sp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```